# How to enable I or Info button for a AWS CloudWatch dashboard via AWS CDK typescript

Tags: typescript, amazon-cloudwatch, aws-cdk, aws-cdk-typescript

I have created a dashboard through AWSCDK typescript but I am not able to see the "i" button which give the information about the metric of the widget:
[image: widget with I button(top right)]

Widget created using the CDK (missing the "i" button):

[image: widget created from code base]

Comment: Can you share the CDK code you used to create the widget? I have created some using the GraphWidget construct and they have the "i" button

Comment: I am using math expression.

export function addMathExpression(
  nameSpace: string,
  metricName: string,
  searchText: string,
  statistic: string,
  // customLabel?: string,
): cloudwatch.MathExpression {
  const expression = `FILL(SEARCH('{${nameSpace}} MetricName="${metricName}" AND(\\\"${searchText}\\\")', '${statistic}'), 0)`;
  return new cloudwatch.MathExpression({
    expression,
    label: `${statistic}`,
    period: Duration.minutes(5),
  });
}